# Cannot play video after record with AVFoundation

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I use AVFoundation to record video, after finish recording this video will run automatically.
This is code to record video:

```
- (IBAction)captureVideo:(id)sender {
if (!isRecording) {
    isRecording = YES;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy||HH:mm:SS"];
    NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    NSString *theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:now];

    NSString *videoPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.mov",documentsDirectory,theDate]];
    outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];
    [movieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:outputURL recordingDelegate:self];
} else{
    isRecording = NO;
    [movieFileOutput stopRecording];

    [self playVideo];
}
}
```

Play video:

```
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:outputURL];
AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [AVPlayerViewController new];
playerViewController.player = player;

playerViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 150, self.view.frame.size.width, 400);
[self.view addSubview:playerViewController.view];
[player play];
```

The weird thing is that I cannot play video after record, but when I put a breakpoint in line `AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:outputURL];`. When program hit this breakpoint, then I continue to run it. It run fine.
I don't know why.
Any help or suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think you should be storing when recording to a buffer/cache or other temporary location instead of right to a file. It will give your video a chance to get recorded and for any OS or processing framework to have a chance to finish it's work before you save to a file. The breakpoint points in that directions since it stops, it gives it a chance to finish writing to the file.

Comment: See this link https://www.objc.io/issues/23-video/capturing-video/ specifically the section about  `AVCaptureDataOutput` and `AVAssetWriter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [Apple's documentation for the stopRecording method in AVCaptureFileOutput](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureFileOutput_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVCaptureFileOutput/stopRecording), we can see that there is a AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate method called `captureOutput:didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:fromConnections:error:`.

So it looks like you're trying to play the video when it's not done writing to the disk. The disk writing is done asynchronously, so when the next line (`[player play]`) is being executed, the video most certainly won't be done writing.

I don't know where you initialized your `movieFileOutput` object, but you should set its delegate (it could be the view controller).

Once that's done, just implement the `captureOutput:didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:fromConnections:error:` method (which is required anyway) and you could put your `[player play]` method in there to play your video (after verifying that no error occured).

Here's an example implementation of that method:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections error:(NSError *)error {

    if ([error code] == noErr) {
        [player play];
    } else {
        //Let the user know something went wrong
        NSLog(@"Error recording to output file: %@",error.localizedDescription);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem.
Instead of call `[self playVideo];` after stop recording. I call it on `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`'s delegate

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections error:(NSError *)error{
    if ([error code] == noErr) {
        [self playVideo];
    }
}
```